# I have difficulty disabling a function in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem when I try to disable a function.
Actually I'm creating a text animation:

```
    function textAnimation()
{
     $('.imagers>p:nth-child(n)').hide();
        $('.sub').hide();
        $('.imagers>p:nth-child(1)').show();
        var scale=1.3;
        $('.imagers>p:nth-child(1)').css('transform', 'scale('+scale+')').wait(2000).hide(200);
}
```

And to have a better experience of the site on mobile, I want to disable this feature to enable another one that is better suited to a mobile phone.
So I tried this function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

         var x = $(window).width();
            $('#sizeInformation').text(x);
           if(x<642)
               {
                  $(document).off(textAnimation());
               }

    });
```

However, the function does not disable and this behaves strangely,
do you have a suggestion please?
At first I thought the condition:

```
if(x<642)
               {
                  $(document).off(textAnimation());
               }
```

was not working.
So I also tried this one:

```
$('body').click(function(){
        $(document).off(textAnimation());
    })
```

But the result is the same, the function behaves strangely and does not disable.
Can you help me, please?
Sorry for my English, I'm French

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to disable a function, make a function that decide which function to call:

```
function responsiveTextAnimation() {
  if ($(window).width() < 642) return textAnimationMobile();
  return textAnimation();
}
```

Now replace every call of `textAnimation()` with `responsiveTextAnimation()` and it will decide if it calls the mobile function or the desktop one.

Comment: I tried this, however when the window is greater than 642 px the function does not turn off.
Do you have a suggestion?                                                                                           
  ' function analytic()
    {
    if($(window).width()<642) 
        return textAnimation();   
    }
    analytic(); '

Comment: But what do you mean by turning off a function?

Comment: In fact I put my animations in a function, so when I disable the function, it should also disable the animations related to the function?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work that way. Actually the function runs only a small fraction of the second, but the wait function that you think run 2 seconds is actually just telling the browser to run something 2 seconds later, it doesn't actually wait. The function then ends immediately and after that 2 seconds it comes alive again for a small split-second. At least that's my guess about what happens, because I only know the basics of jQuery (and even discourage using it). If you want to disable the animation, make a separate function that resets the CSS state to the initial state without transitions.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the windows size then call your function:

```
var x = $(window).width();
if (x > 642) {
    textAnimation();
}
```

Comment: But you would have to do that every time you call the function

Comment: if you write this code in $(document).ready(function(){}) your function is call one time after the DOM is loaded. but if you put this code inside $(window).resize(function() {}) the function call when you resizing the windows.

Comment: The thing is, the OP is not calling the function every time he's resizing the window (would you really like an animation that runs each time you resize?). They are just disabling the function when the event happens without calling it. We don't actually know when and how many times they call it.

Comment: I think, I don't understand your question well. does this code is uploaded anywhere, that I can see?

Comment: I don't know, you should ask the OP in the question's comments, not the answer's

Comment: I think, the user doesn't always change the windows size.

Comment: He doesn't, but it's there so that if he resized to less than 642, it would load the mobile animation. But what the OP wants to know is how to disable a function, not how to make responsive content

Comment: Yes I was wrong, I don't want to execute the animation in "resize function" but when the window has a specific value